# Python : convert unicode string to raw object/text

Tags: python, django, forms, unicode

I've got a set of key, value pairs dictionary in my Django application. The value in the dictionary is a string type.

```
{u'question': u'forms.CharField(max_length=512)'}
```

I need to convert this "value" string to an actual object, and get something like this.

```
properties = {
    'question' : forms.CharField(max_lenth=512)
    }
```

Notice that values in the second dictionary are actual Django form fields and NOT strings. I need to do this manipulation to create dynamic forms. The second dictionary is to be passed to "type" built-in function. Sample code can be found on this page. http://dougalmatthews.com/articles/2009/dec/16/nicer-dynamic-forms-django/ .

Comment: Oh urgh. I can suggest a nicer representation if you like.

Comment: @ignacio : Sure. I'm just learning stuff here. The only constraint is that I need to create forms on the fly/dynamically.

Comment: What Python version are you using Neo?

Comment: @mahmoud - standard 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your code, I suggest to separate field name from field attrs:

```
my_fields = {u'question': {'name': 'CharField', 'attrs': {'max_length': 512} }}
```

and then something like:

```
properties = {}
for field_name, field_def in my_fields.items():
    properties[field_name] = getattr(forms, field_def['name'])(**field_def['attrs'])
```

Answer (score 3):

If you modify your representation a bit:

```
fields = {u'question': u'{"field": "django.forms.CharField", "params": {"max_length": 512}}'}
```

then you can use the following:

```
from django.utils import importlib, simplejson

def get_field(fname):
  module, name = fname.rsplit('.', 1)
  return getattr(importlib.import_module(module), name)

print dict((k.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), get_field(v['field'])(**v['params']))
  for k, v in ((k, simplejson.loads(v)) for k, v in fields.iteritems()))
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Based on clarifying comments by the OP, this isn't an appropriate solution.

---

I don't know the constraints you are under, but perhaps the following representation will work better:

```
{u'question': lambda: forms.CharField(max_length=512)}
```

You can then "realise" the fields thus:

```
dict((k, v()) for (k, v) in props.iteritems())
```

Comment: That's not really a representation though.

Comment: @Ignacio: "Representation" is an extremely broad term that covers statements like, "A lambda function is a representation of a computation". Perhaps you had a more narrowly-defined meaning in mind.

Comment: The question I've posted is a sort of simplification. Actually, I have a database model, that stores Field and corresponding django form field. Ex "Char" -> "form.Charfield(max_lenght=512)" etc. So depending on user input, I retrieve a corresponding string for each field type. Should I store something other than string my model database?

Comment: @Neo: In that case, what you are doing is probably the simplest solution. You can convert any string representing a Python value back to that value using Python's `eval` function.

Comment: Using eval gives me the following error `'module' object has no attribute 'CharField'`. Maybe I should statically declare the objects types in the file as a dictionary, rather than the database.